# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row error comes after fetching some records

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is fetching records in sql developer. But when i run it from ksh file and spool it, partial records get generates and error comes. How can I find out the data for which this error is coming? 
Query is:

```
select im.item as "ITEM",
 (select  val.uda_value_desc 
  from uda_values val,UDA_ITEM_LOV lov 
  where  lov.item=im.item 
     and lov.uda_id=val.uda_id 
     and lov.UDA_VALUE=val.UDA_VALUE 
     and val.uda_id=3) as "SERIE",

 (select  val.uda_value_desc 
  from uda_values val, UDA_ITEM_date lov 
  where lov.item=im.item 
    and lov.uda_id=val.uda_id 
    and val.uda_id=20) as "UDA_DATE"
from ahl_rumm_prod_item_master im;
```

table ahl_rumm_prod_item_master  has 313535 records.

Comment: select list sub-queries are dangerous, left join's are safe.

Comment: Could you explain your intention on that query first? For error, it's clearly that the subquery return more than one row for each `im.item` so you can't use that `multiple row` as `one row for one column`.

Answer (score 3):

One way that make minimal changes to your code is to change your correlated sub-queries to `SELECT COUNT( ... ) FROM ...` and then filter out the rows where something other than one result is returned:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select im.item as "ITEM",
         (select COUNT( val.uda_value_desc )
          from   uda_values val,
                 UDA_ITEM_LOV lov 
          where  lov.item=im.item 
          and    lov.uda_id=val.uda_id 
          and    lov.UDA_VALUE=val.UDA_VALUE 
          and    val.uda_id=3
         ) as "SERIE",
         (select  COUNT( val.uda_value_desc )
          from    uda_values val,
                  UDA_ITEM_date lov 
          where   lov.item=im.item 
          and     lov.uda_id=val.uda_id 
          and     val.uda_id=20
         ) as "UDA_DATE"
  from   ahl_rumm_prod_item_master im
)
WHERE  SERIE    <> 1
OR     UDA_DATE <> 1;
```

This will tell you the items where errors are occurring and you can investigate further.

Comment: a delight to look at well done sql queries in a good format!.

Answer (score 1):

One or both of your inner query return more than 1 row. therefore It cannot be set as a column value. What you should do is add some conditions to the inner queries to make sure that they return just one row